# what does this mean "Unlike BEFORE row triggers, AFTER row triggers lock rows."?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

what does this mean

> Unlike BEFORE row triggers, AFTER row triggers lock rows

I got this statement from below link:

[docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c18trigs.htm](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c18trigs.htm)

Comment: The statement seems perfectly clear to me. What is your confusion?

Comment: Hi Smith, my confusion is that if after trigger locks a rows, is there a way, I can know if this row is locked due to after trigger or due to something else? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its about the AFTER ROW trigger. As per the documentation, *"After modifying each row affected by the triggering statement and possibly applying appropriate integrity constraints, the trigger action is run for the current row provided the trigger restriction was not violated. Unlike BEFORE row triggers, AFTER row triggers lock rows."*

It means AFTER ROW trigger apply lock on the affected rows before completing the extended actions, for data integrity, where as the BEFORE ROW trigger does not apply any lock on the row that is yet to be affected.

Comment: Hi, for me this seems a theoretical concept. How do I quantify it? Is it possible for me to see in database (some views like v$locked_objects), the difference between before/after row trigger?

Comment: Row locks are held in the block itself, not in any central lock table. Since the change that causes the trigger to execute will require a row lock anyway, the issue seems to me to be moot.

Comment: Thanks for your comment David. I understood that concept. I am just concerned about the "exclusive" statement with respect to the difference between before row trigger and after row trigger. Thanks.